# How to deal with broken browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

I have a general question. I'm working on my first program in JavaScript and while I'm working on them I experienced some weird "broken browser"-problems.

During the weeks of work on my program I tested the project often on different browsers and computer systems. While doing it I observed weird behavior on Firefox and Chrome in specific versions. In both cases the program worked fine in both browsers then suddenly I experienced problems in Firefox on Windows on one machine. After some research I tried to update the browser and the problem was gone. The same experience I had on Chrome on Linux. It worked fine, then suddenly I had problems with Chrome 48. I tested the program on Mac and Windows, everything was fine. Then I recognized that the browsers on this machines has the version 54. So I updated on my Linux machine to the newest version and the problem was gone.

My Question: is it normal that such things happen with specific versions of browsers and if so, how to deal with it if you're working on bigger projects?

**Edit:** From the answers below I see that I was not clear with my question. The Question is not really about cross-browser compatibility than more about why a programm works in chrome v47, but not in v48, and then it works again in v54. Same for Firefox and other browsers.

Comment: newer versions of browsers support newer scripting methods for example, ECMAScript 6 is not supported by old browsers. if you want to support users of older browsers, you should make sure that there is code that these browsers can run.

Comment: That a problem is gone does not necessarily mean that the reason that caused the problem is also gone. It still might be that you haven an error in your code that is only exposed in certain browser versions or situations and not that the browser has an error causing your program to fail. Without knowing your code and how it fails it is not possible to tell if the problem is your code or the browser and how to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read about cross-browser compatibility.
Each browser may have different implemenations of  specific functions or even do not have.
For older browsers like IE8 and less even simple `window.innerWidth` 
doesn't work.

[jQuery](https://jquery.com/) may help you. Its library which effectively provides cross browser compatibility for a lot of cases.
Another way to test if browser support some function is using [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/)

You can also check support manually by websites like [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) - works mainly for css styles but also js